# Can you deploy a Sheets addon and run it as an admin or service account?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-groups-api

I have created a sheets sidebar addon which allows a user to select a group and update members based on a column in a sheet.

When I run it as my admin account, everything works; however, when a normal G Suite user runs the addon, they run into issues as the api I'm using to add users to the group is the Admin SDK Directory.

This is the error when I try to run as a normal G Suite user - "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to directory.members.delete failed with error: Not Authorized to access this resource/api"

member = AdminDirectory.Members.remove(str, userEmail); or 
member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, str);

This works fine in a web app if I deploy to run as an admin.

Any guidance or tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have to use Service Accounts https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unfortunately you cannot give a user running the Add-on permissions which that user does not have.

If you want the user to run the script, you need to assign him / his organization unit respective roles or privileges from the [User Admin Console](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1).

I suggest that you [create a custom administrator role](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043) to give the user only the permissions they need to run the Addon.

If you are looking into running Apps Script with a service account, you'll need to install the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) and perform `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` calls with JSON requests.